# Как выполнить большой sql скрипт в powershell?

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, powershell

Есть SQL script с таким псевдокодом:

```
IF EXISTS DROP PROCEDURE
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE 
GO
IF EXISTS FUNCTION DROP FUNCTION
GO
CREATE FUNCTION
GO
IF EXISTS TRIGGER DROP TRIGGER
GO
CREATE TRIGGER
GO
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TransactionName
        if(NotAllow) THROW
        CREATE #tempTable
        #Insert statements
        DROP #tempTable
    COMMIT TRANSACTION TransactionName
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TransactionName
END CATCH
DROP PROCEDURE
```

Полный код

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'Return_All_Email_To_Test')
DROP PROCEDURE Return_All_Email_To_Test
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Return_All_Email_To_Test
@table nvarchar(100),
@column nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max)
    SET @cmd = N'UPDATE [dbo].[' + @table +'] SET ' + @column +' = [dbo].[DecodeEmail](' + @column + ')'
    print @cmd
    exec sp_executesql @cmd
END
GO
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
            FROM    Information_schema.Routines
            WHERE   Specific_schema = 'dbo'
                    AND specific_name = 'DecodeEmail'
                    AND Routine_Type = 'FUNCTION' ) 
            DROP FUNCTION dbo.DecodeEmail
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DecodeEmail 
(
    @mail nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @decodeResult nvarchar(max)
    if(LEN(@mail) > 3 AND CHARINDEX('SummerInfantTest+', @mail) = 1)
    SET @decodeResult = SUBSTRING(@mail, 
    CHARINDEX('+', @mail) + 1,
    LEN(@mail) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@mail)) - CHARINDEX('+', @mail)) 
    + '@'
    + SUBSTRING(@mail,
     LEN(@mail) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@mail)) + 2,
     LEN(@mail) - CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(@mail)) - (LEN(@mail) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@mail))) - 1)
     else
     SET @decodeResult = @mail
    RETURN @decodeResult
END
GO

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TurnOffEmailTest
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.VersionInfo WHERE [Description] = 'Testing emails is turned on') = 0 THROW 51000, 'Emails already turned off', 1

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SICMS_EncodeEmailsForTest]')) DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[SICMS_EncodeEmailsForTest]

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmailsInfoCols') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EmailsInfoCols

    CREATE TABLE #EmailsInfoCols (
        [tableName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [columnName] [nvarchar](100) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'Blog_Comment', N'CommentEmail')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'Blog_Comment', N'CommentUrl')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'Blog_Comment', N'CommentUserName')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'CMS_Email', N'EmailFrom')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'CMS_Email', N'EmailTo')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'CMS_EmailTemplate', N'EmailTemplateBcc')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'CMS_EmailTemplate', N'EmailTemplateFrom')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'CMS_User', N'Email')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'CMS_UserSettings', N'UserMessagingNotificationEmail')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'COM_Customer', N'CustomerEmail')
    INSERT #EmailsInfoCols ([tableName], [columnName]) VALUES (N'CONTENT_Blog', N'BlogSendCommentsToEmail')     

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
            FROM    Information_schema.Routines
            WHERE   Specific_schema = 'dbo'
                    AND specific_name = 'EncodeEmail'
                    AND Routine_Type = 'FUNCTION' ) 
            DROP FUNCTION dbo.EncodeEmail

    declare @table nvarchar(100)
    declare @column nvarchar(100)
    declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for SELECT tableName, columnName FROM #EmailsInfoCols

    open cur
    fetch next from cur into @table, @column

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        exec dbo.Return_All_Email_To_Test @table, @column
        fetch next from cur into @table, @column
    END



    DELETE FROM dbo.VersionInfo WHERE [Description] = 'Testing emails is turned on' 
    DROP TABLE #EmailsInfoCols
    COMMIT TRANSACTION TurnOffEmailTest
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TurnOffEmailTest
END CATCH

DROP FUNCTION dbo.DecodeEmail
DROP Procedure dbo.Return_All_Email_To_Test
```

Скрипт отлично выполняется в SSMS(Sql Server Management Studio). Нужно, чтобы его можно выполнить с помощью powershell скрипта. Powershell:

```
param(
[string]$sqlPath,
[string]$pathToConnectionString
)
if(-not $sqlPath) {
    $sqlPath = ".\finalFilterOff.sql"
}
if(-not $pathToConnectionString) {
    $pathToConnectionString = "..\..\wwwroot\CMS\web.config"
}

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $pathToConnectionString)
$connectionString = $xml.configuration.connectionStrings.add | Select "connectionString"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString.connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = Get-Content $sqlPath
Write-Output $command.CommandText
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connection.Close()

#Push-Location
#invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $sqlPath -serverinstance $serverInstance -database $database  -Verbose
#Pop-Location
```

Если использовать ExecuteNonQuery:
[image: Если использовать ExecuteNonQuery:]

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect
>   syntax near 'GO'. 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement
>   in a query batch. Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. Incorrect syntax near
>   'GO'. Must declare the scalar variable "@mail". Must declare the
>   scalar variable "@mail". Must declare the scalar variable "@mail". A
>   RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. The variable name '@table' has already
>   been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or
>   stored procedure. The variable name '@column' has already been
>   declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored
>   procedure. Incorrect syntax near 'Return_All_Email_To_Test'."

Если использовать invoke-sqlcmd:
[image: Картинка ошибка для invoke-sqlcmd]

> invoke-sqlcmd : Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

В случае с Invoke-SqlCmd всё печально, потому что помимо того, после выбрасывания этой ошибки транзакция остаётся висеть, т.е. Powershell кинул ошибку, а сервер по прежнему выполняет скрипт. Из-за этой транзакции без перезагрузки сервера нельзя получить доступ к таблицам.

Ещё раз обращу внимание, что в SSMS скрипт выполняется без ошибок. Как можно его выполнить с помощью Powershell?

PowershellVersion: Major - 5, Minor - 0, Build - 10586, Revision - 122

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands) на английском SO вашу проблему решили.

Comment: `GO` это не команда SQL. ее понимает именно клиент. Вам надо самому разбивать текст на блоки по `GO` и отправлять эти блоки по череди на сервер, уже без `GO` в тексте